# How to make a 100% stacked Column Chart in Report Builder 3.0 with one value?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, mdx, olap, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Report Builder 3.0 for a Report having a 100% Stacked column chart.
I have a values for different dates, now i want to make a column chart where the maximum value would denote 100% in Y-axis and for each day the cumulative value will fill the lower part of each column.

Is there any expression by which i can calculate the maximum value? Or should i get this value from MDX query?

Comment: do you not have a stacked chart type? I do.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your chart to being a percent stacked column chart, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239318.aspx.

Also if the y axis is not showing a percentage you need format the y axis label as custom using this format `0\%`.